# How to set uiview background and uiimageview to be centered, scaled to fill and masked to bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

Hello I am working on feed and I am facing issues with displaying images correctly. The issue is with first two `UITableViewCells`, that get displayed after tableView loads. The remaining cells load correctly. The code is mention below that I am using to display the images.

Following are some screenshots of the issue.

https://ibb.co/W3rCsmB

https://ibb.co/8PZKVSh

https://ibb.co/jhwm6JH

https://ibb.co/cLyfC3C

```
//Code to add Image. 
//Code written in configurecell() 

let imageURL = URL(string: ForFeed.image_url)
    let media = UIImageView(frame: mediaView.bounds)
    media.downloaded(from: imageURL!)
    media.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    media.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.mediaView.insertSubview(media, at: 0)

//Code to add Background image.
//Code written in awakefromnib()

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mediaView.frame.size)
    let mediaPlaceholder = UIImage(named: "nilmedia")
    mediaPlaceholder?.draw(in: self.mediaView.bounds)

    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.mediaView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }else{
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        debugPrint("Image not available")
    }
```

The result should display images properly.

Comment: Add the screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Added, please check @PGDev

Answer (score 0):

Just headover to storyboard and select he image view and then go to Attribute inspector
set contentView to aspect fill

[image]